# setting PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 for a virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, virtualenv

I would like to set `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable to be permanently set to `utf-8` in a particular `virtualenv`.
So whenever I activate my virtualenv using

```sh
source py/bin/activate
```

my setting of `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` will be automatically activated as well.

I followed [`virtualenv` manual](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/cli_interface.html) and tried the following

```sh
echo $PYTHONIOENCODING ## expected unset

env PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 virtualenv py --python=/usr/bin/python3.6
#Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
#...
echo $PYTHONIOENCODING ## expected unset

source py/bin/activate
echo $PYTHONIOENCODING ## expected to be set here
```

but it didn't work (expected to last command return `utf-8`).

How can this be achieved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+set+environment+variable

Comment: @phd Could you please tell me which of linked 3 questions provide the answer to my question? I see only workarounds there

Comment: All 3. Which one you choose is up to you.

Comment: @phd In none of them I am finding solution with virtualenv. If the answer to my Q is "it cannot be achieved using virtualenv only", then it is a still valid answer. No reason to close question.